# Android WebView Progress bar + Swipe Refresh

Tags: java, android, api

I am new on Android JAVA programming, trying to make this code to work. I tried all the combinations from StackOverflow, and this is the best I got. I manage to get webView and SwipeRefresh to work, but the horizontal progress bar doesn't work, and I don't know why. It just doesn't show when I refresh. Here is the code

**activity_main.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp" />

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swiperefreshlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```js
package com.example.test;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    WebView webView;
    String url = "https://www.google.com";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initControls();
    }

    private void initControls() {
        swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swiperefreshlayout);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);

        //setting webviewclient
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                //To open hyperlink in existing WebView
                view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progressBar.setProgress(0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }

        });
        //setting webchromeclient
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView webView, int newProgress) {
                progressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
            }
        });
        //setting other settings
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        //setting swiperefreshlistener
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                webView.reload();
            }
        });
    }

    public void onBackPressed (){
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test">

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your progressbar is behind the webview

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swiperefreshlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It was just as easy as that hahaha and I didn't see it. Thanks!!!!